# Cannot toggle "Prevent automatic sleeping on power adapter when the display is off"

Tags: macos, display, settings, bug, ventura

I can't toggle the option "Prevent automatic sleeping on power adapter when the display is off" under Settings -> Displays -> Battery & Energy. It just remains on. This looks like a bug. Would there be any workarounds?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

1. **Setting** > **Users & Groups** > **Guest User**, then toggle **Allow guests to log in to this computer**
2. Log out from your official account and log in as a guest.
3. **Settings** > **Displays** > **Advanced**, then toggle **Prevent automatic sleeping on power adapter when the display is off**
4. Confirm this operation by typing your username and password (official account).
5. Log out and log in to your official account.
6. **Setting** > **Users & Groups** > **Guest User**, then toggle **Allow guests to log in to this computer**

I hope that helps you with your problem.